# PHPMyAdmin with php < 8

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

So I am installing PHPMyAdmin for months now on my php 8 machine by using `apt install phpmyadmin`, which always worked fine, it always ran at php 7.2, the webserver at least, not sure if phpmyadmin it self also used php 7.2, anyway, it did not install or use php 8.1

But today, after I tried to install phpmyadmin on 3 different machines I noticed that when using `apt install phpmyadmin` it was installing php 8.1, which is conflicting my Laravel projects which need php artisan functions, which only seem to work with php 8.

So my question is, is there any way to not install php 8.1 but just use 8 or 7.2?

Comment: The simplest option would be to use a Docker container that takes traffic forwarded from Apache. Alternatively, you can install multiple versions of PHP and use a local proxy (configured in the Apache virtual host file) to specify which version of PHP to use 

Comment: well, I am using nginx :P

Comment: Cool. Please [edit] your question to be more complete. The basic premise remains the same, though: use a container or set up an internal proxy that directs to specific versions of PHP. Alternatively, you can *not* use phpMyAdmin and connect to the server with a database client like TablePlus or BeeKeeper 

Comment: Well, I guess ill go with that yea, hoped it to be a bit simpler to be honest. Thanks.

Comment: @UndercoverNL there is nothing *simpler* than [using any modern MySQL GUI client via SSH tunneling](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin). Definitely beats installing phpMyAdmin in regards to security and ease of use.

Comment: well, I now installed PHPMyAdmin on xampp and made all my db's accessable by my home Ip to make it work. I am using phpmyadmin for years and I just like how it works, the userinterface and the functionality without having to know a hundred different commands haha.